# Elementwise median of list of matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

Given a list of matrices:

```
temp <- list(matrix(c(1,8,3,400), 2), 
    matrix(c(5,2,300,14),2), 
    matrix(c(100,200,12,4),2)
)
temp
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    8  400
#
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    5  300
# [2,]    2   14
#
# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  100   12
# [2,]  200    4
```

I want the element-wise median of the matrices:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5   12
[2,]    8   14
```

Can this be done without explicit for loops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, put it into an array:

```
library(abind)
a <- do.call(abind, c(temp, list(along=3)))
```

Then use `apply`:

```
apply(a, 1:2, median)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    5   12
# [2,]    8   14
```

---

As @RichardScriven suggests, you can also build `a` without the abind package:

```
a <- array(unlist(temp), c(2, 2, 3))
# or
a <- array(unlist(temp), c(dim(temp[[1]]), length(temp)))
```

Comment: Essentially, convert to 3d array, and then use apply(). Thanks!

Comment: Loading `abind` can be avoided with `a <- array(unlist(temp), c(2, 2, 3))`.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is `tapply` after `unlist`ing the 'temp'

```
 res <- temp[[1]]
 res[] <- tapply(unlist(temp), rep(seq(length(temp[[1]])),length(temp)), FUN=median)
 res
 #     [,1] [,2]
 #[1,]    5   12
 #[2,]    8   14
```

---

Or another option is `rowMedians` from `library(matrixStats)` after converting the 'temp' to a `data.table` (`setDT(temp)`).

```
 library(data.table)
 library(matrixStats)
 res[] <-  rowMedians(as.matrix(setDT(temp)))
```